# Multi Case Statement

Tags: sql, case

I have the below case statement to group departments into reporting units ...

```
CASE( Department_Text__c, "Administration", "Operations",
"Support”, "Operations",
"Client Services", "Client Services",
"Sport”, "Client Services",
"Creative", "Creative Services",
"Creative Production", "Creative Services",
"Delivery", "Creative Services",
"Design", "Creative Services",
"Editorial”, "Creative Services",
"Finance", "Operations",
"IT", "Operations",
"Legal", "Operations",
"Marcomms", "Operations",
"New Business“, "Operations",
"Paid Media", "Planning",
"People and Culture", "Operations",
"People & Culture", "Operations",
"Production", "Creative Services",
"Research & Insights", "Planning",
"Senior Management", "Leadership",
"Strategy", "Planning",
"Tech/Development", "Creative Services",
NULL)
```

but when I run the statement it gives the error  - **Error: Syntax error. Missing ')'**

I cannot see where the extra ')' would be?

Any help much appreciated

Comment: Looks more like oracle's `decode` than `case`. What dbms are you using? General syntax of [case](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp) is very different from what you wrote.

Comment: `case Department_Text__c when 'Administration' then 'Operations' when 'Support' then ... end`.

Comment: @markalex this is built on the salesforce database.